# Translucent Navigation Bar in iOS 7

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I have been trying to figure this out all day. How do I change the transparency level for the UINavigationBar on iOS 7?

This is what I have tried (with *no* success):

- Setting the UINavigationBar tint colour to have transparency: `[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.01f]]`. This works, but the image as the background for my UIViewController appears to be grayscale.
- Setting the alpha of both the UINavigationBar and the CALayer for the UINavigationBar.

Thank you very much.

Edit: I am trying to achieve something like [this](http://dribbble.com/shots/1145654-Activity-Tracking-App-Concept-and-1-Dribbble-invite/attachments/147835).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it to be possible to make the bar opaque anymore. The link you added does not have an opaque bar either. It is translucent with what looks to be a blue barTintColor.

What I suspect you are trying to do is have your content not covered by the translucent bar. In that case, look at `UIViewController edgesForExtendedLayout`. You probably want `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;`.

Comment: Thank you very very much for the quick reply! My content is not covered by the UINavigationBar, but I am making an app for my school and I was just hoping there would be a way to make the UINavigationBar a little more transparent. Thanks anyways though!